What is the way to build nested widgets such as MDCard containing other widgets inside it?
I am new to coding. I would really appreciate help on this one. I have tried numerous things and scoured the internet for help on this. I tried quite a few things based on other people's problems/solutions but nothing helps for what i need. Please, I am at my wits end battling to figure this out.
I am building an app which should take entries from a database table and populate an MDCard with the fields from that database entry. I am progressively building up to that functionality and right now i am stuck on just building the MDCard.
This is the kivy of what I want to build but I want to execute this from a python function. Here's the kivy as an example:
<ViewScreen>:
    name:'View'

    card_list:card_list

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'

        ScrollView:
            size:self.size

            GridLayout:
                id: card_list
                size_hint_y:None
                height:self.minimum_height
                width:self.minimum_width
                cols:1
                spacing:'20dp'
                padding:'20dp'
                

                MDCard:

                    orientation:'horizontal'
                    padding:'2dp'
                    size_hint:1,None
                    height:'140dp'

                    MDGridLayout:
                        rows:1
                        cols:3

                        MDGridLayout:
                            rows:4
                            cols:1

                            MDLabel:
                                text:"Task Title"
                            MDLabel:
                                text:"Task Description"
                            MDLabel:
                                text:"Budget"
                            MDLabel:
                                text:""

                        MDGridLayout:
                            rows:4
                            cols:1

                            MDLabel:
                                text:""
                            MDLabel:
                                text:""
                            MDLabel:
                                text:"Date Required"
                            MDLabel:
                                text:""

                        MDGridLayout:
                            rows:2
                            cols:1

                            MDIconButton:
                                icon:"bookmark-outline"

                            MDIconButton:
                                icon:"offer"

        Button:
            size_hint: (None, None)
            size:"60dp","30dp"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5,"center_y": 0.05 }
            background_color: (1, 1, 1, 0)
            text: "Refresh"
            color:(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
            on_release:
                root.build_card()

To inject a MDcard into the ScrollView, I tried:
class Task_Card(MDCard):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Task_Card,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation="horizontal"
        self.padding="2dp"
        self.size_hint=(1,None)
        self.height='140dp'

        self.inside=MDGridLayout()
        self.inside.rows=4
        self.inside.cols=1

        self.inside.add_widget(MDLabel(text='Press'))

class ViewScreen(MDScreen,Task_Card):
    
    def build_card(self):

        for i in range(5):
    
            self.ids.card_list.add_widget(self.Task_Card)

I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".\main.py", line 144, in 
class ViewScreen(MDScreen,Task_Card):
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases Layout, BackgroundColorBehavior

That error is due to your ViewScreen class extending both MDScreen and Task_Card. There is no need for ViewScreen to extend Task_Card. I believe you want your ViewScreen to contain Task_Cards, not be a Task_Card. Change that class definition to:
class ViewScreen(MDScreen):

See this question for a discussion realted to your situation.

Thank you for responding to my question. I followed your suggestion but get the following error:
File ".\main.py", line 150, in build_card
self.ids.card_list.add_widget(self.Task_Card)
AttributeError: 'ViewScreen' object has no attribute 'Task_Card'

I guess I was trying to inherit the Task_Card class attributes from Viewscreen class as I expected Viewscreen would have no idea what Task_Card is.

There is a class definition of `Task_Card' That's all that is needed.
